# How to use any item in a list as a split value in Python?

Tags: python, list, arguments, multiple-arguments

I want to do something to the effect of:

```
x = [" ","cats"]
def function(a):
     a.split([any of the elements in x])
     return a
```

How would I make Python accept any of the elements in x as an argument (so it splits as spaces and cats)?

Edit: Sorry, I should have probably specified: a is expected to be a list

(I'm really, really sorry for not being clear.)

input - a = "I love cats so much"
expected output - ["I" , "love","so" , "much"]

Basically, I want it to perform the split function for " " and then for "cats".

Comment: split is a string method and not available for integers as in `x`.

Comment: Do you want it to look like this? [' ','c','a','t','s']? As in you split the elements of the strings up, and return a collectively split string? Please give an example of what you are intending to do.

Comment: Please edit your question to have examples of expected input and output beahvior.  As it is I have no clue what you want.

Comment: Ok, you edited, but what exactly do you mean by "split" then? The string-method "split" would return an empty list for " " and does not change `x[1]`. Please define exactly(!) what split actually should do and provide an example for a. Also, a sample result would be very helpful.

Comment: In another comment, you wrote you wanted to remove "cats", not split actually. It would really be helpful to get the question clear before asking-

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "I love cats so much"
x = [" ", "cats"]

for delim in x:
    s = s.replace(delim, " ")

print s.split()
```

You're making a new list, without any of the cats.

Comment: I want to split it by spaces and also by "cats". Is there any way to do both?

Comment: No. He wants it split by any of the strings in `x`.

Comment: It's not just `cats`. It's any string in the list `x`.

Comment: What if the string is "I love thundercats so much"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. Not the most readable of approaches but gets the job done.

```
import re
x = [" ", "cats"]
pattern = "|".join(x)

re.split(pattern, "I love cats very much")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_many(s, *words):
    return filter(bool, reduce(lambda s, word: 
            s.replace(word, words[0]), words, s).split(words[0]))

print split_many('I love cats so much', 'cats', ' ')
```